# Generate special file list

Tags: bash, list, awk, ffmpeg

How can I get a list like this in bash:
I have to create a list like this and then concatenate the files for ffmpeg.

```
ls -l stream
-rw-r - r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 9 20:30 Il.Gatto.Nero.2019.mp4
-rw-r - r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 9 20:30 My.Name.2019.mp4
-rw-r - r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 9 20:30 Terminator.2019.mp4
-rw-r - r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 9 20:30 spot-Il.Gatto.Nero.2019.mp4
-rw-r - r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 9 20:30 spot-My.Name.2019.mp4
-rw-r - r-- 1 root root 0 Nov 9 20:30 spot-Terminator.2019.mp4

i need to create a txt file like this:

file '/stream/spot-Il.Gatto.Nero.2019.mp4'
file '/stream/Il.Gatto.Nero.2019.mp4'
file '/stream/spot-Terminator.2019.mp4'
file '/stream/Terminator.2019.mp4'
file '/stream/spot-My.Name.2019.mp4'
file '/stream/My.Name.2019.mp4'
file ..........



ls -l | awk {'print "file \047/data/"$9 "\047" '} | awk NF
file '/data/'
file '/data/Il.Gatto.Nero.2019.mp4'
file '/data/Il.Mio.Nome.2019.mp4'
file '/data/Terminator.2019.mp4'
file '/data/spot-Il.Gatto.Nero.2019.mp4'
file '/data/spot-Il.Mio.Nome.2019.mp4'
file '/data/spot-Terminator.2019.mp4'
```

Greetings Mich

in php have write this :

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'genlist';
$db_user = '********';
$db_pass = '********';
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
//echo "Connected successfully";
}
mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name) or die ("Error select db: " . mysqli_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_movie ORDER BY RAND()";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

$data = "file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/" . $result['spot']  . "'"."\n";
$data .= "file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/" . $result['movie'] . "'"."\n";

file_put_contents('/var/www/html/random-cinema-drama.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND );

}


?>
```

php result :

```
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/spot-Demolition.-.Amare.E.Vivere.2015.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/Demolition.-.Amare.E.Vivere.2015.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/spot-Una.Giusta.Causa.2018.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/Una.Giusta.Causa.2018.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/spot-Io.Prima.Di.Te.2016.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/Io.Prima.Di.Te.2016.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/spot-A.Beautiful.Day.2017.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/A.Beautiful.Day.2017.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/spot-Un.Improbabile.Amicizia.2019.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/Un.Improbabile.Amicizia.2019.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/spot-The.Intervention.2016.mp4'
file '/data/EagleCinema/CinemaDramaNew/stream/The.Intervention.2016.mp4'
```

...

i need same result but with bash script no DB, only scan ffrom directory the file and generate the list.

Comment: The order is important, right?

Comment: yes first the spot-moviename.mp4 after moviname.mp4

Comment: Please show what things you have tried and why they don't work.

Comment: I have time to answer on Thursday with the right order. Do not know why the answers do not care about the given order in your question.

Comment: have update the post whit new info.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to format the output of `find` command like this:

```
find . -printf "file '%p'\n"
```

Read more about the `find` command and its formatting options [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215234/explanation-of-directives-in-find-printf).

Sample output:

```
file './tomcat-docbase.8602702943778820035.8020'
file './tomcat.7980157961655295062.8020'
file './tomcat.7980157961655295062.8020/work'
file './tomcat.7980157961655295062.8020/work/Tomcat'
file './tomcat.7980157961655295062.8020/work/Tomcat/localhost'
file './tomcat.7980157961655295062.8020/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT'
file './tomcat-docbase.7948873979763860512.8020'
file './metadata'
file './chrome-win.zip'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right order in the output:

```
#!/bin/bash

filelist=$(find stream -name '*.mp4' -exec basename {} \; | grep -v '^spot-')
rm -f file.txt

for f in $filelist ; do
    echo "file '/stream/spot-$f'" >>$file.txt
    echo "file '/stream/$f'" >>$file.txt
done
```

First I collect only the files without the "spot-" in front in a filelist and then output the list with and without the leading "spot-".

Answer (score 0):

i think you can replace `ls` output line breaker with "file "

```
ls | tr '\n' '\nfile '
```